# Inheritance woes: Using header files and default constructor of the base class in the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, mingw, codeblocks

I have got a simple question:
Here is the base class:

```
class CBox
{
public:

    double m_Length;
    double m_Width;
    double m_Height;
    CBox()
    {

    }
    CBox(double lv=1.0,double wv=1.0,double hv=1.0)
            :m_Length(lv),m_Width(wv),m_Height(hv)
        {
        }
    ~CBox();
protected:
private:
};
```

And here is the derived class:

```
 #ifndef CCANDYBOX_H

    #define CCANDYBOX_H

   #include "CBox.h"

   #include <iostream>

   #include <cstring>


class CCandyBox :CBox
{
    public:
         char* m_Contents;
        CCandyBox(double lv, double mv, double hv, char* str):CBox(lv,mv,hv)
        {
            m_Contents = new char[ strlen(str) +1 ];

            for(unsigned int i=0; i< strlen(str)+1; i++)
            {               *(m_Contents+i) = *(str +i);
            {
                *(m_Contents+i) = *(str+i);
            }

        }
        CCandyBox(char* str = "Candy"):CBox()
        {
              m_Contents = new char[ strlen(str) +1];

              for(unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(str)+1;++i)
              {
                  *(m_Contents +i) = *(str+i);
              }
        }
        virtual ~CCandyBox()
        {
            delete[] m_Contents;
        }
        CCandyBox(const CCandyBox& other);
        CCandyBox& operator=(const CCandyBox& other);
    protected:
    private:
};


#endif // CCANDYBOX_H
```

Main.cpp function just includes "CCandyBox.h" and a simple "helloworld"

And gives the following errors:

```
        C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|4|error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'namespace'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|4|error: expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|4|error: expected ';' before 'namespace'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|4|error: expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|11|error: expected '}' at end of input|
C:\Work\Check\CCandyBox.h||In constructor 'CCandyBox::CCandyBox(double, double, double, char*)':|
C:\Work\Check\CCandyBox.h|24|error: expected primary-expression before '(' token|
C:\Work\Check\CCandyBox.h|24|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'|
C:\Work\Check\CCandyBox.h|24|error: expected ';' before ':' token|
C:\Work\Check\CCandyBox.h|41|error: expected '}' at end of input|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp||In member function 'int CCandyBox::main()':|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|9|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|9|note: suggested alternative:|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++\iostream|62|note:   'std::cout'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|9|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|9|note: suggested alternative:|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++\ostream|543|note:   'std::endl'|
C:\Work\Check\main.cpp|11|error: expected unqualified-id at end of input|
||=== Build finished: 16 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I am using MinGW with CodeBlocks. Help appreciated

Comment: ¤ The base class has *two* default constructors. The standard defines a default constructor as one that can be called without any argument, and the base class has two such. That's allowed, but it makes it impossible to default construct an instance, since the constructor choice is ambiguous. A simple fix is to remove the argument defaults for the second constructor, and make the first one initialize with `1.0` values. That will also avoid the current *indeterminate values* that the first constructor currently yields (none of the members are initialized). Cheers & hth.,

Comment: General comments: don't prefix class names with `C` (or anything else), do (in general) make the destructor `virtual` in a class designed to be derived from, don't use `unsigned` variables as numbers (they're good for bits though), and don't use cryptic shortenings: do make the code *readable* and *self documenting*. Cheers,

Comment: Uhm, and a final observation, do use e.g. `std::string` instead of raw character array pointed to by a `char*`, and in general, preferably do use standard library containers instead of dealing directly with raw pointers and raw arrays and raw dynamic memory allocation and deallocation. You may want to google the c++ *rule of three*. It concerns a problem that using `std::string` here avoids.

Comment: I second all of Alf comments, and when asking a question, do post the actual code. The first error of the compiler refers to something around the keyword `namespace` that is not present in the posted code. It is advisable to solve compiler errors one at a time from the first one (after the first error, the parser might be confused about the meaning of each identifier, and that in turn can cause bogus errors, solve the first one, then go for the second one)

Answer (score 1):

1. For starters, I'd strongly suggest making life easy on yourself and move all your implementation bodies to separate files (for example, to CBox.cpp and CCandyBox.cpp).
2. This is wrong:

   for(unsigned int i=0; i< strlen(str)+1; i++)
       {               *(m_Contents+i) = *(str +i);
       {
           *(m_Contents+i) = *(str+i);
       }
3. This is better:

   for(unsigned int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
       m_Contents[i] = str[i];
     m_Contents[strlen(str)] = '\0';
4. This is even better:

*file CCandyBox.h:*

```
#ifndef CCANDYBOX_H
#define CCANDYBOX_H

#include <string>
#include "CBox.h"

class CCandyBox : public CBox
{
    public:
    std::string m_Contents;
    ...
```

*file CCandyBox.cpp:*

```
#include <string.h>
#include "CCandyBox.h"
...
CCandyBox::CCandyBox(double lv, double mv, double hv, char* str)
  : CBox(lv,mv,hv)
{
  m_Contents = std::string(str);
  ...
```

Comment: Bring strlen out of the loop iteration. `for(unsigned int i=0, l = strlen(str)+1; i < l; ++i)`

Comment: `CCandyBox::CCandyBox(double lv, double mv, double hv, char* str)
  : CBox(lv,mv,hv), m_Contents(str) {}`